# I want to be able to distribute instances which are snapped to a triangular grid within a volume

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to fit a load of hexagonal objects together within a volume. I have them snapped to a triangular grid using two mesh lines, one of which has every other vertex displaced 0.866 in Y. I've then generated the volume I want this to fit within, which is also a hexagonal shape. This will appear based on a map (currently a musgrave texture), like this:

https://vimeo.com/825833092/1f45105408?share=copy

How do I cull the point cloud I've got (shown here with hexagonal proxy objects) so only the points within the volume above are included?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I worked it out. I didn't need it to be a volume - using the Raycast node with the hexagonal mesh as a target, then feeding the Is Hit output through a boolean Not node to Delete Geometry, this gives a point cloud which only contains those points which are above the large hexes (in this case).
[image]